# Automate web login for Wi-Fi hotspots (captive portal) on Windows

Tags: windows, automation, wifi, authentication, captive-portal

Many Wi-Fi hotspots these days have a "web login", especially free ones. You know, the ones that redirect any HTTP request to their login form.  (The technical term for the technique is "[captive portal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal)".)  Constantly logging into these manually is a pain, especially if you use the same ones all the time.

Is there a program out there that can automate such logins, i.e. save my username and password for a given hotspot, detect that the hotspot currently requires a login (i.e. captive portal detection, which Windows itself does) and actually perform the login without any action on my part?

Note that this capability [exists for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.uk.syslynx.wifiwebloginapp) and, I believe, iOS.

Comment: Note that I am copying the text from [this unjustly closed question](http://superuser.com/questions/656100/automate-web-login-for-wi-fi-hotspots) on SuperUser.SE.

Comment: It is a fact that SuperUser.SE is not made for this kind of questions... That's why Software Recommendations was created, and this is a great question for here :-) Could you please specify your OS, though, or split your into for instance 5 questions (for Android/iOS/Windows/Mac/Linux). There is probably no app that supports all 5 platforms, so splitting is the best in this case. Thanks and welcome to SR!

Comment: You had a "windows" tag so I guessed your question is for Windows, and changed the title to reflect that. I also created the same question for Android: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3974/automate-web-login-for-wi-fi-hotspots-captive-portal-on-android Not sure to understand the "like Windows does" part of the question though.

Comment: Windows 8 appears to have this built-in.

Comment: Well Nicholas,  that SuperUser question was actually reopened in response to my objections, so not everyone agrees with you. I'm actually of the opinion that SoftwareRecommendations has a dubious mission (due to it being essentially built around a type of question rather than a topic). But that's a discussion for elsewhere.

Comment: Dan-o could you explain this better? Maybe you're just thinking of the automatic connection for wifi networks *without* captive portals?

Comment: Yes Nicolas, I did intend it for Windows.  Thanks for clarifying and for creating that other question.

Comment: There seems to actually be a question of this asked on SO as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248679/automatic-login-script-for-a-website-on-windows-machine

Comment: Look at [this Linux utility](https://github.com/ussjoin/portalsmash), it's designed to automatically parse and accept captive portals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seem to be a number of options on how to do this. Unfortunately, there's no real pure Windows application. They all seem to rely on scripts and the like.

As One of the [SuperUser quetions](https://superuser.com/questions/430995/how-can-i-automatically-log-into-a-network-with-a-captive-portal-in-windows) pointed out, there is a scripting tool called [WebInject](http://webinject.org/) that could be used to make a script that opens up the page and logs in for you. As I mentioned in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248679/automatic-login-script-for-a-website-on-windows-machine), there is a scripting tool called AutoHotKey that could also do this.

In terms of automating these, a good technique would be to use the Task Scheduler on Windows, and create an on-login event for your computer (I believe you would be looking for code [508](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventid=528), which is the event for successfully logging onto the local computer).

Comment: This seems to be the best answer available so I'm accepting it. But if someone else finds something better (or something better is released) I hope they post it.

Comment: Or, worse comes to absolute worse, I may just write one, and post to it here...