# Automate web login for Wi-Fi hotspots (captive portal) on Android

Tags: android, automation, wifi, authentication, captive-portal

Many Wi-Fi hotspots these days have a "web login", especially free ones. You know, the ones that redirect any HTTP request to their login form.  (The technical term for the technique is "[captive portal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal)".)  Constantly logging into these manually is a pain, especially if you use the same ones all the time.

Is there an Android program out there that can automate such logins, ie. save my username and password (for a given hotspot), detect that it requires a login and actually perform the login without any action on my part?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are [several apps for that](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=196#group_429) available. I personally used **[WiFi Web Login](http://www.appbrain.com/app/co.uk.syslynx.wifiwebloginapp)** in the past, and even bought the [pro key](http://www.appbrain.com/app/co.uk.syslynx.wifiwebloginappactivate) for this app. It works pretty well:

You have to once record your captive login (i.e. you start the app, say to add a new "portal", and *then* manually start your login procedure from within the app. Once done, this is recorded as macro; as soon as you switch on your WiFi next time, and that portal's SSID is recognized, *WiFi Web Login* will automatically replay the recorded macro – et voila, you're logged in without any additional tap.

Some screenshots to visualize this for better understanding:

[image: registered events] [image: new recording] [image: playback mode] [image: recording]
<sup>*WiFi Web Login:* Available recordings, record a new portal, playback in progress, example macro (source: Google Play; click images for larger variants)</sup>

Comment: User [ooo](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/22957/ooo) pointed out (via flag): *this app is reportedly not working for every user, see app comments.* Still works for me, though. Checking the mentioned comments, the app seems to have issues with Android 5+.

Comment: It looks like here in 2019 the `WiFi Web Login` does support modern Android versions. The [author writes](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidyou.wifiloginnew&hl=en_US) "It supports the latest Android 5.1.1, Android M (6.0 and 6.01) , Android N (7), Android M(8) and Android O"